# Inherit props and functions from vue parent instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to define some default props and functions in my vue instance that i want to reuse in all of my components. How do i go about doing this? I have tried to pass the props but since they are read only it wont work.

Am i approaching this in the right way or should i look at another way?

```
// vue.js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import Page from './vue-instances/Page';

const Vue = createApp({
 data() {
  return {
    loading: false // default prop
  };
 },
 components: {
   Page
 }
});
Vue.mount('#vue-app');
```

---

```
// Page.vue
export default {
 props: { loading: Boolean },
 data() {
   return {
     title: 'New Page',
   };
 },
 mounted: function () {
   setTimeout(() => {
     this.loading = true; // Reuse inherited props 
   }, 1000);
 }
};
```

Comment: ...it seems [mixins](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html#mixins) is what you looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is not the best.
If you are trying to reuse a data (the said prop) for a certain purpose, try creating a component that uses that data and reuse the said component, that would be a more natural and inline way of going about UI development.